# Rename Multiple Files in a Directory in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a requirement to rename all files (not single file) in a directory with the current time stamp in LINUX.

For example:

```
abcd_001_@timestamp@_12345.txt, abcd_002_@timestamp@_56789.txt
```

to

```
abcd_001_20141205063435_12345.txt, abcd_002_20141205063435_56789.txt
```

I have used `rename` command but unable to change the names. Could someone help me here.
A quick reply will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you try and how did it fail? That would help guide the answers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename @timestamp@ $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) *@timestamp@*
```

See also `man rename` for details and more examples

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to rename them manually, then you could use something like this:

`rename 's/@timestamp@/20141205063435/' *.txt`

If you want to do it automatically you could use the `date` command to give you the current date.

`rename "s/$(date)/$(date +%Y%m...)/" *.txt`

Comment: The `rename` you provide an example for is not part of the `util-linux` package found on most Linux boxes by default. Your example is apparently for a perl script named rename. You need to make sure you make the distinction otherwise it could cause data loss.